# Showing all values in a column where no relatable data is present

Tags: mysql

So lets say I run a shop. In this shop, I have six employees. These employees report every sale into a MySQL database. If an employee doesn't make a sale, he makes no entries into that system in the week. Pay day comes around, and I need to figure out how much to pay everyone based on sales:

```
Select Staff, count(Item_Sold) from Inventory where Sale_Date between '2013-05-02%' and '2013-05-08%' group by Staff;
```

I would most likely get the output of:

```
Staff       Items_Sold
Aaron       6
Bob         2
Jeff        4
Karen       13
```

Now lets assume I have never fired anyone, and the staff always stays the same. Lets also say that they have made sales in the past. Say I want to see all employees in my weekly report, regardless whether or not they made any sales. How would I fit that into my query without getting rid of the 'Date' correlation? I.E.

```
Staff       Items_Sold
Aaron       6
Bob         2
Geraldo     0
Jeff        4
Karen       13
Mary        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called a `left join`. Here is a good explanation: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Basically, a left join will return all results from the first table regardless of weather or not they have related data in the second table.

Comment: With this issue, all pertinent information is located within the same table. Can you call the same table twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate table of Staff (and you should), you can do this with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Staff.Name, count(Item_Sold)
FROM Staff
LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Staff.Name = Inventory.Staff
WHERE Sale_Date BETWEEN '2013-05-02%' AND '2013-05-08%'
GROUP BY Staff.Name
```